# Ruby instance variables not available inside methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, instance-variables

I can't figure out why the instance variable `@delivery_options` isn't accessible from within the individual mailer methods...

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    @delivery_options = {
            user_name: 'foo',
            password: 'bar',
            address: 'smtp.foobar.net'
    }

    def invite_email (email, project)
        logger.debug( @delivery_options ) #WHY IS THIS IS UNDEFINED??
        @project = project

        #THIS WORKS FINE
        mail(to: email, subject: "WORK DAMMIT", delivery_method_options: {
                user_name: 'foo',
                password: 'bar',
                address: 'smtp.foobar.net'
        })

        #THIS FAILS
        #mail(to: email, subject: "WORK DAMMIT", delivery_method_options: @delivery_options)

    end


end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first instance variable definition (`@delivery_options`) is available only to the class, not its methods. That's why you're running into this problem. Class variables (`@@delivery_options`) are available to all methods in a class, but aren't as frequently used because class variables are not inherently thread safe.

All this said, you probably want to use a constant to define these and just reference the constant. Or, even better, set some default delivery options using [ActionMailer's default system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails) like so:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default {user_name: 'foo', password: 'bar', address: 'smtp.foobar.net'}

  ...
end
```

All defaults are applied to every method in the mailer, but overriden by any options you specify locally.

Answer (score 3):

If these are "static" data, you could just do:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    DELIVERY_OPTIONS = {
        user_name: 'foo',
        password: 'bar',
        address: 'smtp.foobar.net'
    }

    def invite_email(email, project)
        mail(to: email, subject: "WORK DAMMIT", delivery_method_options: DELIVERY_OPTIONS)
        ...
    end
end
```

This should work.

If you want to use an instance variable, you should do something like:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    def initialize
        @delivery_options = {
            user_name: 'foo',
            password: 'bar',
            address: 'smtp.foobar.net'
        }
    end

    def invite_email(email, project)
        mail(to: email, subject: "WORK DAMMIT", delivery_method_options: @delivery_options)
        ...
    end
end
```

This way, the variable is defined on the instance of UserMailer you are using.
The way you did it was defining an instance variable on the UserMail class.

Comment: Cool. I'm a Ruby n00b but I think your code uses a constant. I'll give it a try. In the mean time, can you explain why the scope of the instance variable doesn't reach into the methods. Is that not normal Ruby practice?

Comment: Edited my answer to add some explanations.